# How to display correct link in CI anchor

Tags: codeigniter

I have a form with upload file option.
I get the **file_path** on **$data** uploaded by user. Now I want to use this 
`file_path` to be the link in my anchor tag.

My problem is i can't get the correct link. it seems like that the base URL was being included in the link showed in the lower left of the screen.

I also read some post here to add `"http://"`  before the link. but the link appeared was like this

```
c/xampp/htdocs/.../uploads/products/filename.pdf
```

no colon.

any idea on how can I access my uploaded file be access via link.

Thanks

Comment: use base_url().

Comment: @SachinAghera, I already tried this but still not solved my problem. i also put prep_url(), no avail.

Comment: May I see your code where you want to use the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste this line in your /applications/config/config.php just right before

`$config['base_url'] = "";`

and change this to

```
$protocol = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ? 'https://' : 'http://');    
$root = $protocol.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $root;
```

This approach makes your base_url() function returns the current host or url you are in. Even if you upload this to any server it will always return the exact url of your website.

Then you use it like this

```
<?= base_url('uploads/products/filename.pdf'); ?>
```

That's all you have to do. Hope this helps!